# Drive list files doesn't have nextPageToken when `fields` is present

Tags: google-drive-api

When running this list files there is not a `nextPageToken` there is just `files[]`.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(id%2C%20name)&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

result:

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "1"
  },
  ...
  {
   "id": "2",
   "name": "2"
  }
 ]
}
```

Leaving the `fields` parameter empty, the `nextPageToken` is returned.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

result:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9FV7TN...",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1",
   "name": "1",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  },
...
```

Is this a bug or is there some way to get the `nextPageToken` and limit the fields returned?  The [doc page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter) for `fields` implies that it should work:

> Note: The Drive API supports query parameters for data pagination (maxResults and nextPageToken). For APIs that support these parameters, use these parameters to reduce the results of each query to a manageable size. Otherwise, the performance gains possible with partial response might not be realized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `fields=files(id,name)` is used for the method of "Files: list", the file ID and filename are returned. In this case, the values of fields are `files.id` and `files.name`. `nextPageToken` is not included in `fields`. By this, the page token is not returned. When `fields` is not used, it seems that `fields` of `nextPageToken,incompleteSearch,kind,files(id,name,kind,mimeType)` is the default value. So I thought that this is not a bug, and it might be the current specification.

So when you want to retrieve `nextPageToken` when you use `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(id%2C%20name)`, please include `nextPageToken` in `fields` as follows.

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles%28id%2Cname%29&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

- In this case, `fields` is `nextPageToken,files(id,name)`.

#### Result:

When above curl command is run, the following result is returned.

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "###",
 "files": [
    {"id": "###", "name": "###"},
    {"id": "###", "name": "###"},
    ,
    ,
    ,
 ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: This worked just fine.  I was focused on the `files()` and had tried putting `nextPageToken` in there, but that is the wrong level.  I submitted a suggestion to the doc page to show off that possible mixture of levels.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.